How to plot 3-D waterfall map of an x-y grid using python by including IPyWidgets?
I would like to plot 3-D waterfall maps for an x-y grid as shown in the figure. I wish to do this using IPyWidgets such that if user has x-position = 10 in the slider or box of the IPyWidget,  then one can see the 3-D waterfall map of all the points along y-position. Each point on the grid has a 2-column dataset for example Frequency (along y-axis) vs Time (along x-axis), where the Time column remains same for all grid points. The shape of each dataset can be (5500, 2).
So I guess dataframes can be handy to either store all the dataset in single dataframe or one has to prepare separate dataframes for each value of x-position. It would also be interesting if we can keep both x-position and y-position as a slider/box as IPyWidget. I do not have an initial code from myside yet, but would really appreciate if you can assist. Thank you!
